# How can I reference a clicked ActionLink `a` element from within it's OnBegin function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

How can I reference the clicked `Ajax.ActionLink` from within it's `OnBegin` function?

**cshtml**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    typeName,
    "OrderQueueRows",
    new 
    {
        typeNames = Model.Name,
        includeDerivedTypes = ViewBag.IncludeDerivedTypes,
        excludeCompletedOrders = ViewBag.ExcludeCompletedOrders
    },
    new AjaxOptions {
        LoadingElementId="ajax-loading",
        OnBegin = "highlightFilter",
        UpdateTargetId = "order-queue-body"
    },
    new { @class = "show-exclusively" })
```

**javascript**

```
function highlightFilter() {
    $link = $(this);
    $link.css('color', 'red');
    $link.siblings().not($link).css('color', '');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with the out-of-the-box `Ajax.*` helpers because they do not pass the element to the `onBeforeSend` callback. The way Microsoft implemented it, they pass the `xhr` object and not the `element` that was clicked. So one possibility is to modify the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in order to pass this information to the callback. On line 85 you will see the following inside the `beforeSend` callback:

```
result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply(this, arguments);
```

All you have to do is to modify it like this:

```
result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply(element, arguments);
```

and if you needed to have both the element and the xhr object inside your `OnBegin` callback:

```
result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply({ xhr: this, element: element }, arguments);
```

Now, your code is going to work and `this` will represent the element:

```
function highlightFilter() {
    $link = $(this);
    $link.css('color', 'red');
    $link.siblings().not($link).css('color', '');
}
```

Another possibility is to simply replace the Ajax.ActionLink with a standard Html.ActionLink and then write the corresponding jQuery code to subscribe to the .click event and trigger the AJAX request. Personally it's probably what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in ASP.NET MVC 5.1, using approach from another stackoverflow question: [How to use $(this) inside MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink OnBegin,OnComplete Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630189/how-to-use-this-inside-mvc3-ajax-actionlink-onbegin-oncomplete-events/14611314#14611314)