# Get calling form in OnSuccess

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

```
<div class=".parentForm'>
    @Ajax.BeginForm(... AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "submitSuccess" })
    {...}
</div>

function postDone(result,two, three) {
   $('.parentForm').replaceWith(result);
}
```

I don't like this because if there are multiple forms from this partial they will all have the same class, and I would rather not come up with some funky scheme where I generate an ID on the server side and have to pass it around to the JS callbacks.

With .ajax I can use the `this` to get the form that submitted the request, then from there get the parent .formContainer.  Is there any way to get a referrence to the form that submitted the form with OnSuccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is an easier way though you still have to modify the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file. Add one line of code around line # 100. I provided the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630189/how-to-use-this-inside-mvc3-ajax-actionlink-onbegin-oncomplete-events/14611314#14611314)

```
options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });

options.context = element; // <--- Add this line

method = options.type.toUpperCase();
if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
    options.type = "POST";
    options.data.push({ name: "X-HTTP-Method-Override", value: method });
}
```

**Update**: AaronLS has created an issue on codeplex to see if they would make the change to the jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax file itself, upvote it if you would like this change added as well!

[Codeplex Issue: Let 'this' reference the source element](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/10335)

Comment: +1 but hoping for a different workaround since this will get blown away everytime I update the file with a newer version.

Comment: I agree, I've looked all over for a way to submit this as a change request to Microsoft or whom ever maintains this file but in spite of it being easily available on Nuget, there is no other information for where the project lives or how to propose changes like this. I can tell you that they have not made any updates to the file recently, but that's still no substitution for an actual fix.

Comment: They have an issues section on aspnet codeplex that covers mvc, there's also a uservoice.com ASP.NET MVC site, and then of course connect.microsoft.com.  As far as submitting a patch, they explicitly state they don't except patches,etc. on the codeplex site.  So while it is open source, it isn't open to contributors, AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with those (though had forgotten about UserVoice), however I was unsure of using them because of being unsure who maintains the project (ASP.NET or a diff team). Maybe I'll give it a shot and see if they are open to the fix, worse case they don't make the change, which is where we're at now. Just saw your issue on CodePlex (+vote) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, but you need to modify jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file. You must replace the following lines:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    asyncOnSuccess(element, data, xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "text/html");       
    getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"), ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(this, arguments);
},
```

with:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    asyncOnSuccess(element, data, xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "text/html");
    var args = $.merge(arguments, [element]);
    getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"), ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(this, args);
},
```

can access form in that way:

```
function submitSuccess(result, status, xhr, element) {
    // element is your form
}
```

Comment: +1 but hoping for a different workaround since this will get blown away everytime I update the file with a newer version.