# How can I get sender tag on OnBegin function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, actionlink

I have a list that each row has a link created by Ajax.ActionLink. I want to access to tag which clicked on OnBegin function and convert it to jQuery object.

Thanks :)

**Update**

this is my action code that creates a link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("linkText", "action", new AjaxOptions()
{
    OnBegin = "myfunction",
})
```

this is the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunction() {
     //I need refer to link that clicked
   }
</script>
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this function for ajax.actionlink

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

In the htmlAttributes, you can give the `new {class='lnk'}`

Use jQuery to find the link which you are clicked using `$(this)` You can also get the parent, next html elements.

Eg (jQuery):

```
$('.agree').live("click", function(){
        var currentId2 = $(this).parents(".user").attr('id');
        alert (currentId2);
        call the function() you are supposed to call in ActionBegin

});
```

A sample demo, in that I have lot of div and I have a link on each. I need to find the clicked link (all links are having class with name as `agree`.

Another references

[How to use $(this) inside MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink OnBegin,OnComplete Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630189/how-to-use-this-inside-mvc3-ajax-actionlink-onbegin-oncomplete-events)